# What is the fastest way to find the bottleneck/optimize Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to identify quickly a faulty script in Magento that slows down the server?

Magento has something like 35 000 files, so there are so many places it can go wrong, I just need a way to find quickly where to optimize.

For example, could I install a script that would tell me all the files magento reads before outputing a page? And then tell me how much time it takes for each file to execute?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xdebug and [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) will profile your application.

Though it can be a bit tricky to set up, so I'll just post my configuration and you can take from it what you can (from my WampDeveloper installation)...

php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\WampDeveloper\Components\Php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
```

Webgrind's config.php

```
static $storageDir = 'D:/WampDeveloper/Temp/webgrind';
static $profilerDir = 'D:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always Magento's built-in profiler. It's a configuration change and a file edit away.

[Enabling Magento Profiler](http://www.neptuneweb.com/blog/discuss/24-identifying-magento-performance-problems-with-the-magento-profiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are also some other extension that may help you finding bottlenecks for example the [ecocode Magento Profiler](https://github.com/ecoco/magento_profiler) or [mgt developer toolbar](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer-toolbar.html)